# A renderflex overflowed by 17 pixels on the right

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]

**"A RenderFlex" overflowed by 17 pixels on the right**
**Row**

so i tried to add expanded widget around containers and column in order to solve this problem out.

The relevant error-causing widget was Row.

Do you have some solutions how to fix it please.

```
------ Column

Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                                  10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 15.0),
                              child: Row(
                                mainAxisAlignment:
                                    MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                children: [
                                  Text(
                                    product.weight,
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.black,
                                      fontSize: 16.0,
                                      fontFamily: 'BuffetMedium',
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Container(
                                    margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                        horizontal: 5, vertical: 0),
                                    height: 30.0,
                                    width: 65.0,
                                    child: FlatButton(
                                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                        borderRadius:
                                            BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                                      ),
                                      color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                                      textColor: Colors.red,
                                      padding:
                                          EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5.0),
                                      onPressed: () => print(product.id),
                                      child: Row(
                                        mainAxisAlignment:
                                            MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                        children: [
                                          Text(
                                            '+ ' + product.priceBefore,
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                                fontSize: 15.0,
                                                color: Colors.white),
                                          ),
                                          Icon(
                                            FontAwesomeIcons.rubleSign,
                                            size: 13.0,
                                            color: Colors.white,
                                          )
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

remove the width property, since the text and icon take up more space than you are giving it by default

```
Padding(
padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 15.0),
child: Row(
  mainAxisAlignment:MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
  children: [
    Text(
      product.weight,
      style: TextStyle(
        color: Colors.black,
        fontSize: 16.0,
        fontFamily: 'BuffetMedium',
      ),
    ),
    Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5, vertical: 0),
      height: 30.0,
      // width: 65.0,
      child: FlatButton(
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius:
              BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
        ),
        color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
        textColor: Colors.red,
        padding:
            EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5.0),
        onPressed: () => print(product.id),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment:
              MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Text(
              '+ ' + product.priceBefore,
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 15.0,
                  color: Colors.white),
            ),
            Icon(
              FontAwesomeIcons.rubleSign,
              size: 13.0,
              color: Colors.white,
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ],
),
```

Comment: I believe he will still have a problem if the 'product.weight' text is long.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the `product.weight` Text in a `Flexible` and set `maxLines` and `overflow` for the `Text` widget.

Example:

```
Flexible(
                  child: Text(
                    product.weight,
                    maxLines: 1,
                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.black,
                      fontSize: 16.0,
                      fontFamily: 'BuffetMedium',
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    ------ Column

Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                                  10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 15.0),
                              child: Row(
                                mainAxisAlignment:
                                    MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                children: [
                                  Text(
                                    product.weight,
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.black,
                                      fontSize: 16.0,
                                      fontFamily: 'BuffetMedium',
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Container(
                                    margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                        horizontal: 5, vertical: 0),
                                    height: 30.0,
                                    child: FlatButton(
                                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                        borderRadius:
                                            BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                                      ),
                                      color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                                      textColor: Colors.red,
                                      padding:
                                          EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5.0),
                                      onPressed: () => print(product.id),
                                      child: Row(
                                        mainAxisAlignment:
                                            MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                        children: [
                                          Text(
                                            '+ ' + product.priceBefore,
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                                fontSize: 15.0,
                                                color: Colors.white),
                                          ),
                                          Icon(
                                            FontAwesomeIcons.rubleSign,
                                            size: 13.0,
                                            color: Colors.white,
                                          )
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
```